# SSL form POST from one site to another

Tags: encryption, ssl, webforms, http-post

I am attempting to do a POST securely from one website to another. Instead of trying to do our own encryption or hashing I would like to use SSL. Is it possible to do a form post from one site to another using SSL that would be completely secure for transferring the user information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect the user's browser to another site with POST (the redirect will switch to a GET), but you can certainly have one server initiate a POST to another site over SSL.

Comment: I too fell into this pit while POSTing payment data from my site to a PSP. Once we switched to SSL the POST magically switched to a GET and form-encoding changed from what was specified in the page and form-tag to UTF-8. I wonder why they created this limitation...

Answer (score 2):

A simple form post should work.

```
<form action="https://theirsite.com/Form.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="UserName" value="Quickfire55" />
</form>
```